# Junk table name is getting generated and added in system tables in oracle

Tags: oracle

While running our process random tables are getting created with name like this  `BIN$xGf2aDIQ07bgUxnq9QrvVw==$0`. Not sure how are they getting generated by themselves. Any idea?

Comment: This is a recyclebin. Please, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm#ADMIN11683) for more details.

Comment: You can query the `user_recyclebin` view (or `dba_recyclebin` if needed) to see the objects in [the recycle bin](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-16E1CE4C-0189-4CF5-8047-F5039587D130), including the object type, its original name and when it was dropped. That should help you figure out what your process is doing.

Answer (score 0):

These are objects in recycle bin, e.g.

```
SQL> select * From tab;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
ADHERENT                       TABLE
ADMIN_REGISTRATION             TABLE
AUDIT_TABLE                    TABLE
AUDIT_TBL1                     TABLE
BASE                           TABLE
BIN$v05hK8D0Y6HgU8lkAQqVqw==$0 TABLE
BIN$v05rTFDqUODgU8lkAQo1og==$0 TABLE
BIN$v05rTFDrUODgU8lkAQo1og==$0 TABLE
BIN$v05rTFDwUODgU8lkAQo1og==$0 TABLE
BIN$v3OGPz/pGrngU8lkAQoglg==$0 TABLE
BIN$v3OGPz/qGrngU8lkAQoglg==$0 TABLE
<snip>
```

How do objects get there? When you drop them. If you don't need them (i.e. you won't be retrieving anything from recycle bin), simply *purge* it:

```
SQL> purge recyclebin;

Recyclebin purged.

SQL> select * From tab;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
ADHERENT                       TABLE
ADMIN_REGISTRATION             TABLE
AUDIT_TABLE                    TABLE
AUDIT_TBL1                     TABLE
BASE                           TABLE
BONUS                          TABLE
BOOK                           TABLE
<snip>         --> see? no more BIN$...
```

Comment: but for me select * From tab; is coming null. These tables name i can see in system tables like all_tab_partitions but not in dba_tables. Also  on one environment we have dropped the tables but another we dint but still these are generating . Any other possible issue ?

Comment: This was just a demonstration. As I said: purge recyclebin.

Comment: And it never happened till now we are dropping the objects the similar way . What could be the reason this time these tabels got generated . I just want to avoid any such thing to be happening in production.

Comment: If you don't want to use recycle bin, **disable** it. At session level: `ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = OFF;`, or at database level: `ALTER SYSTEM SET recyclebin = OFF SCOPE = SPFILE;` (it requires you to restart the database). If you can't do it yourself, talk to DBA (because they probably turned it ON).

Comment: I tried to replicate it so while creating the table only it is creating this junk partition

Answer (score 0):

These objects created when you drop a table.
Ex:

```
drop table xyz;
```

but if you drop table with `purge`, the recyclebin tables does not get created

```
drop table xyz purge;
```

to delete these recyclebin tables you can use

```
purge recyclebin;
```

you can also delete recyclebin table one by one

```
PURGE TABLE test;
```

or

```
PURGE TABLE BIN$v05rTFDrUODgU8lkAQo1og==$0;
```

Comment: purging the table giving me error - sql command not properly ended. Also in the dba_objects I just see the  object type as partitions for these tables. Object type = table is not coming. but in all_tab_partitions its coming with table_name also as BIN$v05rTFDrUODgU8lkAQo1og==$0. Also as in  other env I have not dropped the tables still this is coming so I am afraid it wont come into production later